# How to create unknown numbers of HTML tables

Tags: python, html, django, python-2.7

I am trying to render a table using Django-Python. Let us say I have a record of last names starting from A-Z. Now, I want to create a table based on each letter, and put all the people with that first-letter last name on their own table.

```
EX:
TABLE A Last names
  Adams
  Anderson

TABLE B Last names
  Barnes
  Bill
  Brandon 

TABLE J Last names
  Jackson
  Johnson 

etc….   ## this is the output I want to achieve
```

HTML:

```
  <legend>Customers</legend>    
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      {% for idx in people %}
        <td>{{ idx.0 }}</td>
        <td>{{ idx.1 }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    context = {
        "people": People.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

I can easily render this. However, I am trying to separate everyone based on their last name by creating as many as 26 tables. I want them to all appear in the same html page, but separated by tables accordingly. I don’t know how many letters I have from the database and I am trying to avoid hard-coding a table with A-Z header. This is because in my app, it is possible that out of 26, I only have 5 letters available. For looping in the html using the {% tags %} are very helpful.

I have been trying to create a table inside of a loop in html but I'm getting funny results. Can anyone please help me out?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You need the [`{% regroup %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) tag.

```
{% regroup people by firstname.0 as initials %}

{% for initial in initials %}
    <h2>TABLE {{ initial.grouper }} LAST NAMES</h2>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      {% for person in initial.list %}
        <td>{{ person.firstname }}</td>
        <td>{{ person.lastname }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endfor %}
```

Note, your view needs to sort the people by lastname for this to work:

```
context = {
    "people": People.objects.all().order_by('lastname')
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel,
Thanks! I’ve never used this regroup tag before. I will give it a try now. Thanks again :)